# Why are the inequalities equivalent?

Tags: calculus, induction

I saw a proof here on stack of the inequality

$$n^{(n+1)} > (n+1)^n \quad (1)$$

for $n\geq 3,$ by mathematical induction.

One suggested that the above inequality is equivalent to the inequality

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < n \quad (2)$$

How do I show this equivalence? I tried raising both sides in (1) to the $1/(n+1):$th power, but I could not make the RHS to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Divide both sides by $n^n$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $n^{-n}$ to get
$$ n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n
\iff n = n^{n+1} \cdot n^{-n} > (n+1)^{n} n^{-n} = \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$n^{n+1} =n^n \cdot n \implies n^n \cdot n > (n+1)^n$$
Then divide both sides by $n^n$:
$$n> \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$$
and you're done.